# Using Q to get reports not equal to

Tags: django, django-views

I'm on the last step of my view and I can get all reports to return using `QVReportList.objects.all()` it shows the report ID correctly in my template.

However I'd like to use Q to show only the reports that don't exists in my reportdetail shown below:

```
def profile(request):
    owner = User.objects.get (formattedusername=request.user.formattedusername)
    reportdetail = QVReportAccess.objects.filter(ntname = owner.formattedusername).values('report_id','report_name','report_access')
    reportlist = QvReportList.objects.filter(~Q(report_id = reportdetail.report_id))
#    excludedlist = QvReportList.objects.filter(report_id = reportlist.Report_ID)

    print(reportlist)
    args = {'user':owner, 'applicationaccess':reportdetail, 'applicationlist':reportlist}#, 'excluded':excludedlist}

    return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', args)
```

When I try to run it as it I get an AttributeError that states report_id doesn't exist, but it does when I can render it with applicationaccess.report_id and applicationlist.report_id:

```
AttributeError at /account/profile/
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'report_id'
```

Why does it state the object has no attribute report_id?  It clearly exists in the existing database table and my models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not with `Q` object but the issue is in following line:

```
reportdetail = QVReportAccess.objects.filter(ntname = owner.formattedusername).values('report_id','report_name','report_access')
reportlist = QvReportList.objects.filter(~Q(report_id = reportdetail.report_id))
```

In the second line, you are trying to get `reportdetail.report_id` however, reportdetail is Queryset object(list of dict) and it doesn't have `report_id` attribute i.e. why it is saying

> 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'report_id'

Comment: What would be the correct way to get the report_id(s) from the same filter as reportdetail?

Comment: reportIds = QVReportAccess.objects.filter(ntname = owner.formattedusername).values_list('report_id', flat=True)

Comment: and get reportlist as QvReportList.objects.filter(~Q(report_id__in= reportIds))

Comment: Thank you for your help Mohammad, worked like a charm.  For my knowledge?  What does the double underscore followed by In represent?  Is this typically best practice?

Comment: These are lookups. Read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups